# Autoloading non-PSR0 libraries in Symfony 2.0.x

Tags: php, symfony, autoload, psr-0

The `Symfony 2.0 Autoloader` expects that the libraries it can handle follow the `PSR0` or `PEAR` standard when auto-loading files. If you have an old library which does not follow any of these two standards (in my case, class files are named like name.class.php), how would you handle auto-loading of these libraries?

In `Symfony 2.1` this is easy as composer supports `classmaps` and can load this type of libraries, but how would you do it in `Symfony 2.0.x`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Inside `app/autoload.php`, create an instance of `MapClassLoader`:

```php
use Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\MapClassLoader;
use Symfony\Component\ClassLoader\UniversalClassLoader;

// Create default PSR-0 autoloader
$loader = new UniversalClassLoader();
$loader->registerNamespaces(array(
    'Symfony' => array(__DIR__.'/../vendor/symfony/src', __DIR__.'/../vendor/bundles'),
    // ...
));

// Create map autoloader
$mapLoader = new MapClassLoader(array(
    'MyComponent' => __DIR__.'/../library/mycomponent.class.php',
    // ...
));

// Other configurations
// ...

// Register autoloaders
$loader->register();
$mapLoader->register();
```

Comment: My file contains more than one class... Is this solution suitable for my specific case? Moreover, I register my "old" php file with MapClassLoader: then have I to use it like it is registered into autoloader (so use `src/to/my/file/folder/path`) ?

Comment: you should then just be able to do `$obj = new \mycomponent.class.php;`