# require_once() and autoloader - How to load flat php?

Tags: php, symfony

I have a file (an xmlrpc library for PHP) that I would like to use into a Symfony2 class (so inside a Symfony2 project).

I can't use autoloader because as written [here](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/components/class_loader.html)

> which is able *[the autoloader]* to load classes from files that
>   implement one of the following conventions:
>
> ```
> 1) The technical interoperability standards for PHP 5.3 namespaces and 
>    class names;
> 2) The PEAR naming convention for classes.
> ```
>
> If your classes and the third-party libraries you use for your project
>   follow these standards, the Symfony2 autoloader is the only autoloader
>   you will ever need.

the class that I'll go to use, didn't satisfies one of those requirements.

So if I can't autoload that file, since isn't possible (as I understand, but I can go wrong) to use `require_once` (or simply `require`) with `namespace`, what is the solution for this issue?

Comment: I asked a similar question and was given great advice. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11903432/autolading-non-psr0-libraries-in-symfony-2-0-x

Comment: @CarlosGranados My file contains more than one class... Is this solution suitable for my specific case? Moreover, I register my "old" php file with MapClassLoader: then have I to use it like it is registered into autoloader (so use `src/to/my/file/folder/path`) ?

Comment: I think it should work. What composer does is register a map of classes and where they "live". You then just add "use" statements for those classes. If they don't use namespaces just add use classname. If they use namespaces add use FQN

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have a file named `xmlrpc.lib.php` with the following content:

```php
<?php 
class XMLRPC_Server {
    // ...
}

class XMLRPC_Request {
    // ...
}

class XMLRPC_Response {
    // ...
}
```

You can create an instance of `MapClassLoader` to handle it's autoloading:

```php
// Create map autoloader
$mapLoader = new MapClassLoader(array(
    'XMLRPC_Server' => __DIR__.'/../library/xmlrpc.lib.php',
    'XMLRPC_Request' => __DIR__.'/../library/xmlrpc.lib.php',
    'XMLRPC_Response' => __DIR__.'/../library/xmlrpc.lib.php',
));

// Register autoloader
$mapLoader->register();
```

When one of these classes will be auto-loaded, others will be auto-loaded too because they share the same PHP file.

Comment: This is a good way for do that. We use another "trick" that is worst than yours: whe create a "wrap" class that use `require_once()` and so will include that file with all of those class. Then we use MapClassLoader onto that file and it works... Isn't good as your solution, but it works ;-)